# Are cap staples eventually visible under asphalt roof shingles?

Tags: roof, shingles

I am going to replace the roof on my barn using synthetic underlayment and asphalt shingles.

I plan to use 1" cap staples on the underlayment as the manufacturer suggests.

My question is: Once the sun has a chance to soften up the shingles will those caps cause any kind of visible bulge in the shingles?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably. I wouldn't do that. Modern fiberglass shingles are fairly thin compared to the organic (paper) mat ones of the old days, and you will likely see the bulges after a few hot days.

The manufacturer probably only recommends using cap staples under the assumption that it will sit exposed for some period of time and needs to hold up to the wind. It's completely pointless otherwise, as a million shingle nails eventually hold it down anyway.

Comment: You can also get the thin metal disks and use staples through them.  Those wouldn't be visible under a silk shingle.

Answer (score 1):

I did finally get around to installing the roof.  I did use cap staples and architectural shingles.  Cap bulges are not visible in the final roof.

Comment: They wouldn't show immediately, as I mentioned in my answer. It takes time for shingles to mold to what's under them. How long has it been? Have you had any warm weather?

Comment: yes warm weather.  Also I asked a GAF and a Owens corning rep at a trade show.  Both of them said the caps will not show.